# m and s keys do not work over vnc connection to ubuntu server

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard, vnc

I'm new at setting a lot of this up, so bear with me.

I installed Ubuntu 10.4 server on a 64 bit machine. Then I added vnc so I could manage it while it's racked.

I start the server, SSH to it, and run

```
# vncserver :1
```

At this point, all keys work fine. Next I exit out of the SSH session and fire up my client vnc app. I connect via the IP :1, enter my password, and everything seems to be fine. Now when I enter a terminal (through the vnc connection) I cannot type lowercase "s" or "m" (upper case works). I've tried on two different pc's running the vnc client, but it's the same. I also installed the latest updates from Ubuntu as of today.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this explains the issue...

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/indicator-applet/+bug/568401